# Flutter Firebase auth user is not persistent on the device

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase phone auth in my Flutter application for android. The login system works properly. However, every time I open the app, it returns null user. Due to which, I have to login every time I open the app. I don't know if this is a bug or a mistake on my end but I'll share the code with you guys over here.

PhoneAuth code:

```
enum PhoneAuthStatus {
  SignedIn,
  CodeSent,
  HasError,
  SignedOut,
}


class PhoneAuth with ChangeNotifier {
  String verificationId;
  final FirebaseAuth phoneAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  PhoneAuthStatus phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedOut;

  PhoneAuth.initialize() {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    currentUser = await phoneAuth.currentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
      phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedOut;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedIn;
    }
  }

  PhoneAuthStatus get status => phoneAuthStatus;
  FirebaseUser get user => currentUser;

  Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String phNum) async {
    phoneAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phNum,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 90),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          AuthResult authResult;
          try {
            authResult =
                await phoneAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
          } catch (error) {
            phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.HasError;
            notifyListeners();
            return;
          }
          currentUser = authResult.user;
          uid = currentUser.uid;
          phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedIn;
          notifyListeners();
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException authException) {
          print(authException.message);
          phoneAuthStatus = (PhoneAuthStatus.HasError);
          notifyListeners();
        },
        codeSent: (String vId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
          phoneAuthStatus = (PhoneAuthStatus.CodeSent);
          notifyListeners();
          verificationId = vId;
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String vId) {
          verificationId = vId;
        });
    return;
  }

  Future<void> signInWithPhoneNumber(String code) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: code.toString(),
    );
    AuthResult authResult;
    try {
      authResult = await phoneAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (error) {
      phoneAuthStatus = (PhoneAuthStatus.HasError);
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
    currentUser = authResult.user;
    phoneAuthStatus = (PhoneAuthStatus.SignedIn);
    notifyListeners();
    return;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    phoneAuth.signOut();
    phoneAuthStatus = (PhoneAuthStatus.SignedOut);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

main.dart code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: PhoneAuth.initialize()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: app_name,
        // routes: Routes.routes,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        )
        home: Container(
          child: LocationError(currentWidget: HomePage()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The init() function should return PhoneAuthStatus.SignedIn. However, it returns PhoneAuthStatus.SignedOut because the currentUser is null.
Please help me and tell me if I'm doing anything wrong. Thank You.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check with placing `notifyListeners()` outside of if block?

```
     currentUser = await phoneAuth.currentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
      phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedOut;
     
    } else {
      phoneAuthStatus = PhoneAuthStatus.SignedIn;
    }
 notifyListeners();
```

and another guess is, you are calling a future method inside a init() method. maybe that's why you are always getting auth status as signOut.

"The **init** method is synchronous by design. Rather than creating the FutureBuilder widget in the **init** method, you could return the FutureBuilder widget in the overridden build method. Feel free to take a look at the documentation for the FutureBuilder widget here for an example of how this could work."

So, I think it is better to use a future builder for verifying the user's presence.

Comment: I've used notifyListeners() properly. I will try it in FutureBuilder and let you know. Thanks.